# Jenkins pipeline NoSuchMethodError (copyArtifacts)

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

this question in some forms has already been asked, but all questions/answers I found did not help me in my case :(

I have the following Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    copyArtifacts projectName: 'producer', selector: specific('lastCompleted'), filter:'*.json'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to copy an aritfact from another job. This fails with 
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'specific' found among steps`.

Can anyone spot, why this is occurring? As far as I can see, I do not mix the declarative vs scripted form... I understand that it tries to find `selector` not for `copyArtifacts`, but for `script`, right ?

But how to make this correct ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the version of your Copy Artifact Plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Error log was misleading.

Installing Copy Artifact plugin helped in my case.
https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/